# TestCafe, Selector withAttribute works with string but not with regular expression

Tags: regex, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When I try to switch to an iframe in TestCafe with the selector bellow:

```
const iframeCase = Selector('iframe').withAttribute('title', 'SR-1234');
```

I successfully switch to the iframe. But since the numbers in the title changes every test run. I need to add a regular expression, as I do here:

```
const iframeCase = Selector('iframe').withAttribute('title', /SR\-[0-9]{0,6}/);
```

But with this regular expression variant I receive the following error:
**The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.**

This is the iframe I'm trying to select:

```
<iframe name="TestGadget8Ifr" id="TestGadget8Ifr" border="0" frameborder="0"style="" title="SR-1234" 
data-hammerhead-focused="true"></iframe>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I first thought that my regular expression was wrong. But other combinations like:

```
  /SR/ 
  /SR\-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ 
  /SR[-0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/
```

All failed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try ,

```
await t.switchToIframe(
    Selector("iframe[title^='SR']"),
    { timeout: 60000 }));
```

Comment: Hi Vysakmohan, Unfortunately that didn't help :(

Comment: Check if document.querySelector("#PegaGadget7Ifr") in console is returning your iframe

Comment: document.querySelector("#PegaGadget7Ifr") is returing the iframe in my console. But the number in the id changes every time the test runs. So I can't really use the ID.

Comment: Try this selector:  Selector("iframe[title^='SR']");

Comment: Unfortunately that selector doesn't work. I did update my question above a little bit since I had some new findings.